# HTML5 Click() / getElementByID not working on SAP

Tags: html, autohotkey, sap-business-bydesign

I tried to automate a process on our SAP Webinterface but it did not work. I wanted a left-sided menu to show and to click into the search bar which appeared at the bottom with one Hotkey.
I used the following code which worked well on other Websites like Google calendar but not on SAP.

```
^!s::
        wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
        wb.Visible := True
        wb.Navigate("http://ThisIsNotTheRealURL.com")
        while wb.busy
            sleep 100
            btn := wb.document.getElementById("__button0")
        btn.Click()
        
    Return
```

If it could help, here is the code of the button I try to click:

```
<div tabindex="0" title="Work-Center-Navigation einblenden/ausblenden" class="sapBUiBelNavIcon sapBUiIcon-shellMenu sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button0" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Work-Center-Navigation einblenden/ausblenden" data-sap-ui="__button0"></div>
```

I would really appreciate some help because I need this for work.

Thanks in advance,

Sonic

**EDIT** (HTML copied from the "answer" posted by the author):

Here is the whole page as HTML:

`<html class="sapBUiShell   sap-desktop  sapUiTheme-sap_belize sapUiMedia-Std-Desktop sapUiMedia-StdExt-LargeDesktop" lang="de" style="overflow: hidden;" dir="ltr" data-sap-ui-browser="ed15" data-sap-ui-os="win10" data-sap-ui-animation="on"><head> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`

`<link href="resources/sap/b/themes/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">`

`<script type="text/javascript"> window["sap-b-config"] = { "data-sap-b-theme": "sap_belize", "data-sap-b-launchpad": "true" };       </script>`

`<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js?version=2" type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m">`

`</script><script id="sap-ui-bootstrap-cachebusted" src="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap-ui-core.js?version=2"></script><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.ui.core" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true"><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.m" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/m/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true">`

`<script src="resources/sap/b/extlib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

`<script id="sap-b-application" src="resources/sap/b/ApplicationStarter.js" type="text/javascript" data-sap-b-clientversion="1708.5.0" data-sap-b-buildtimestamp="20171004104928" data-sap-b-gitcommitid="a0c58f071138ebcee3d3a21f8bbe48ee4f627582">`

`</script>`

`<link href="resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/Startup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.b" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true"><style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family: 'SAP-icons';src: local('SAP-icons'),url('https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/base/fonts/SAP-icons.woff2') format('woff2'),url('https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/base/fonts/SAP-icons.woff') format('woff'),url('https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/base/fonts/SAP-icons.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}</style><title>Mein Launchpad - SAP Business ByDesign</title><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.b.addon" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/b/addon/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true"></head>`

`<body class="sapUiSizeCompact sapBUiShellBackground" role="application" style=""><div id="sap-ui-static" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; float: left;" data-sap-ui-area="sap-ui-static"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiBLy" id="sap-b-ui-blocklayer-popup" style="left: 0px; top: 60px; right: 0px; bottom: 27px; display: none;"></div><span class="sapUiInvisibleText" id="__text1" aria-hidden="true" data-sap-ui="__text1">Aktualisieren mit F5</span></div>`

`<div class="sapBUiContent" id="content" data-sap-ui-area="content"><div id="__shell0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-ui="__shell0"><div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"><div class="sapBUiBelTitle" id="__title0" role="banner" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;" data-sap-ui="__title0" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true" data-sap-ui-popup="__title0"><div class="sapBUiNoPrint" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0;"><div tabindex="0" title="Work-Center-Navigation einblenden/ausblenden" class="sapBUiBelNavIcon sapBUiIcon-shellMenu sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button0" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Work-Center-Navigation einblenden/ausblenden" data-sap-ui="__button0"></div><img class="sapBUiBelCompanyLogo" id="flexCompanyLogo" src="resources//sap//b//themes//sap_belize//img//branding_logo_belize.png"></div><div class="sapBUiNoPrint" style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; overflow: hidden; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><div class="sapBUiBelProductTitle" id="__text0" data-sap-ui="__text0">Mein Launchpad</div><span class="sapUiHiddenPlaceholder" id="sap-ui-invisible-__icon0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-sap-ui="sap-ui-invisible-__icon0"></span></div><div class="sapBUiBelPrintTitle">Mein Launchpad</div><div class="sapBUiNoPrint" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0;"><div tabindex="0" title="Suchen" class="sapBUiBelTitleIconL sapBUiIcon-search" id="__button2" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Suchen" data-sap-ui="__button2"></div><div tabindex="0" title="Tony Ungrade" class="sapBUiBelTitleIconL sapBUiRoundButton" id="__button3" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; align-items: center;" data-sap-ui="__button3"><div class="sapBUiRoundButtonIcon" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><div class="sapBUiRoundButtonIconImg" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden;"><img style=" max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/img/user_placeholder.jpg"></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Randleiste einblenden/ausblenden" class="sapBUiBelTitleIconL sapBUiIcon-help" id="__button1" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Randleiste einblenden/ausblenden" data-sap-ui="__button1"></div></div></div></div><div style="overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1;"><div class="sapBUiNoPrint sapBUiToolboxBackground" style="display: flex; flex-shrink: 0;"><div class="sapBUiShMnu sapBUiShMnuCollapsed" id="__menu0" role="navigation" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow-x: hidden; width: 72px; " data-sap-ui="__menu0" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true"><div class="scrollbox-y scrollbox-delayed" style="flex-grow: 1;"><div class="scrollbox-y-content sapBUiShMnuScrCont ui-sortable"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroupCont"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroup" id="__group0" data-sap-ui="__group0"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShMnuItem sapBUiShMnuItemHighlight sapBUiShMnuItemSelected sapBUiIconHintGray" id="__item5" data-sap-ui="__item5"><div class="sapBUiShMnuItemHint" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div><div title="Mein Launchpad" class="sapBUiShMnuItemIcon" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroupCont"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroup" id="__group1" data-sap-ui="__group1"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShMnuItem sapBUiIconHintGray" id="__item7" data-sap-ui="__item7"><div class="sapBUiShMnuItemHint" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div><div title="Startseite" class="sapBUiShMnuItemIcon" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuArrow sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" style="display: flex; flex-shrink: 0;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroupCont ui-sortable-handle"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroup" id="__group2" data-sap-ui="__group2"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShMnuItem sapBUiIconHintGray" id="__item22" data-sap-ui="__item22"><div class="sapBUiShMnuItemHint" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div><div title="Projektteam" class="sapBUiShMnuItemIcon" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuArrow sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" style="display: flex; flex-shrink: 0;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuFltr" style="flex-grow: 0;"><div class="sapMSF sapMSFDisabled" id="__field0" style="width:100%;" data-sap-ui="__field0"><form class="sapMSFF" id="__field0-F"><input disabled="disabled" class="sapMSFI" id="__field0-I" aria-disabled="true" type="search" placeholder="Suchen" autocomplete="off"></form></div></div><div style="display: none; height: 30px; flex-grow: 0;"><div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiToolboxSeparator"></div><div class="__sapBUiShHdr" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><div class="sapBUiShellMainCont" style="width: 100%; height: 253px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1; align-items: stretch;"><div class="__sapUiBCATB" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; position: relative;"></div><div class="__sapUiBCACA" style="width: 1400.92px; height: 253px; display: flex; position: relative; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; align-items: stretch;"><div id="__presenter0" style="display: flex;  width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-sap-ui="__presenter0"><div class="sapBUiTransparentPaper" id="__component0" data-sap-ui="__component0"><table class="sapBUiContentTable"><tbody><tr class="sapBUiWcViewComponent"></tr><tr height="100%"><td style="vertical-align: top"><div class="sapBUiViewContainer" id="__container1" data-sap-ui="__container1"><div class="sapBUiComponent" style="padding-right: 0px;"><div class="sapFlexLPContainer" id="__view0" data-sap-ui="__view0"><div class="sapBUiLPTabBar sapBUiTSPne sapMITB sapMITBBackgroundDesignSolid" id="__bar0" data-sap-ui="__bar0"><div class="sapContrastPlus sapMITBNotScrollable sapMITH sapMITHBackgroundDesignSolid" id="__bar0--header" role="tablist" data-sap-ui="__bar0--header"><span class="sapMITBArrowScroll sapMITBArrowScrollLeftInLine sapMITBArrowScrollLeftTextOnly sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__bar0--header-arrowScrollLeft" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons'" data-sap-ui="__bar0--header-arrowScrollLeft" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span><div class="sapMITBScrollContainer" id="__bar0--header-scrollContainer" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;"><div tabindex="0" class="sapMITBHead sapMITBInLine sapMITBTextOnly" id="__bar0--header-head"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMITBFilter sapMITBFilterDefault sapMITBItem sapMITBItemNoCount sapMITBVertical sapMITBSelected" id="__filter0" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="__bar0-content" aria-labelledby="__filter0-text" data-sap-ui="__filter0"><div class="sapMITBText" id="__filter0-text" dir="ltr">Arbeit: Eingang</div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMITBFilter sapMITBFilterDefault sapMITBItem sapMITBItemNoCount sapMITBVertical" id="__filter1" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="__bar0-content" aria-labelledby="__filter1-text" data-sap-ui="__filter1"><div class="sapMITBText" id="__filter1-text" dir="ltr">Service und Support</div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMITBFilter sapMITBFilterDefault sapMITBItem sapMITBItemNoCount sapMITBVertical" id="__filter2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="__bar0-content" aria-labelledby="__filter2-text" data-sap-ui="__filter2"><div class="sapMITBText" id="__filter2-text" dir="ltr">Favoriten</div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div></div></div><span class="sapMITBArrowScroll sapMITBArrowScrollRightInLine sapMITBArrowScrollRightTextOnly sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__bar0--header-arrowScrollRight" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons'" data-sap-ui="__bar0--header-arrowScrollRight" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div><div class="sapMITBContentClosed" id="__bar0-containerContent"><div class="sapMITBContent" id="__bar0-content" role="tabpanel" style="display: none"></div></div></div><div class="sapMScrollCont sapMScrollContV" id="__container2" style="width: 100%; height: 186px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;" data-sap-ui="__container2"><div class="sapMScrollContScroll" id="__container2-scroll"><div class="sapBFlexCntArea" id="__area1" style="height: 590px;" data-sap-ui="__area1"><div class="sapBFlexQLGroup" id="__group3" data-sap-ui="__group3"><span class="sapFlexLPGroupHeader sapMText sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" id="__text4" style="text-align:left" data-sap-ui="__text4">Arbeit: Eingang</span><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Posten" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile0" data-sap-ui="__tile0"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Posten</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Posten" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon21" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon21" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Alarmmeldungen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile1" data-sap-ui="__tile1"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Alarmmeldungen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Alarmmeldungen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon23" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon23" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Aufgaben" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile2" data-sap-ui="__tile2"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Aufgaben</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Aufgaben" class="sapUiIcon" id="__icon25" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon25" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Benachrichtigungen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile3" data-sap-ui="__tile3"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Benachrichtigungen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Benachrichtigungen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon27" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon27" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Rückfragen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile4" data-sap-ui="__tile4"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Rückfragen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Rückfragen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon29" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon29" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBFlexQLGroup" id="__group4" data-sap-ui="__group4"><span class="sapFlexLPGroupHeader sapMText sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" id="__text5" style="text-align:left" data-sap-ui="__text5">Service und Support</span><div tabindex="0" title="Erste Schritte" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile5" style='width: 260px; background-image: url("resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/img/getting_started_tile2.png");' data-sap-ui="__tile5"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Erste Schritte</div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Idee einreichen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile6" data-sap-ui="__tile6"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Idee einreichen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Idee einreichen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon33" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon33" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Community befragen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile7" data-sap-ui="__tile7"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Community befragen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Community befragen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon35" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon35" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="One-Stop-Infocenter" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile8" data-sap-ui="__tile8"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">One-Stop-Infocenter</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="One-Stop-Infocenter" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon37" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon37" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBFlexQLGroup" id="__group5" data-sap-ui="__group5"><span class="sapFlexLPGroupHeader sapMText sapMTextBreakWord sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" id="__text6" style="text-align:left" data-sap-ui="__text6">Favoriten</span><div tabindex="0" title="Startseite - Weitergegebene Aufgaben" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile9" data-sap-ui="__tile9"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Startseite - Weitergegebene Aufgaben</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon39" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" aria-label="favorite" data-sap-ui="__icon39" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div><div id="__presenter1" style="display: flex;  width: 100%;" data-sap-ui="__presenter1"><div class="sapBUiMessageAreaOverview" id="__area0" data-sap-ui="__area0"></div></div><span class="sapUiHiddenPlaceholder" id="sap-ui-invisible-__info0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-sap-ui="sap-ui-invisible-__info0"></span></div><div style="display: flex; flex-grow:0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div></div><div class="sapBUiNoPrint sapBUiShTabSw" id="__switch0" data-sap-ui="__switch0" data-sap-ui-popup="__switch0"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShTabSwHomeItem" id="__item0" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1;" data-sap-ui="__item0"><div class="sapBUiShTabSwItemInner" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1; overflow: hidden; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;"><div title="Mein Launchpad" class="sapBUiShTabSwItemTitleContainer" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1; align-items: center; overflow: hidden;"><div class="sapBUiShTabSwItemText" style="display: flex; align-items: center; overflow: hidden;"><div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Mein Launchpad</div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShTabSwPad"></div></div></div></div>`

`<div class="sapUiHidden sapUiForcedHidden" id="sap-ui-preserve" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden;"></div><div class="sapBUiWaterMark"></div></body></html>`

Comment: Could be lots of reasons.  Some content that is delivered and displayed dynamically (AJAX, etc.) will not make it to the DOM.  What happens when you try to return the innerHTML of the element by `MsgBox btn.innerHTML()`?  Do you get the button label, or nothing?  If nothing, you will need a different approach (e.g., using keyboard shortcuts or mouse navigation).  Good luck.

Comment: It does show nothing.Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Based on the div you pasted, I'm guessing that .click() will not work here. There is likely a form to submit or a javascript function that should be called from your script instead. You can execute javascript like so:

```
wb.Navigate("javascript:formSbmt();")
```

In this example, the function formSbmt() will execute on the webpage.

Comment: Thx I will try that.

Comment: How am I supposed to get a form? I can´t find any form in the DOM Explorer. The Thing I try to click is a button to uncollapse a menu from the left side.

Comment: Any chance you can paste the HTML of the page here?

Comment: I've posted the HTML.

Comment: I cant figure it out. Have you tried setting some breakpoints in the dev tools to see what happens when you click the button?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the whole page as HTML:

```
    <link href="resources/sap/b/themes/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon">                

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window["sap-b-config"] = {
        "data-sap-b-theme": "sap_belize",
        "data-sap-b-launchpad": "true"
    };      
    </script>

    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="resources/sap-ui-cachebuster/sap-ui-core.js?version=2" type="text/javascript" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m">
    </script><script id="sap-ui-bootstrap-cachebusted" src="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap-ui-core.js?version=2"></script><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.ui.core" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true"><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.m" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/m/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true">
    <script src="resources/sap/b/extlib/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script id="sap-b-application" src="resources/sap/b/ApplicationStarter.js" type="text/javascript" data-sap-b-clientversion="1708.5.0" data-sap-b-buildtimestamp="20171004104928" data-sap-b-gitcommitid="a0c58f071138ebcee3d3a21f8bbe48ee4f627582">
    </script>
<link href="resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link href="resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/Startup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.b" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true"><style type="text/css">@font-face {font-family: 'SAP-icons';src: local('SAP-icons'),url('https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/base/fonts/SAP-icons.woff2') format('woff2'),url('https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/base/fonts/SAP-icons.woff') format('woff'),url('https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/ui/core/themes/base/fonts/SAP-icons.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}</style><title>Mein Launchpad - SAP Business ByDesign</title><link id="sap-ui-theme-sap.b.addon" href="https://my340472.sapbydesign.com/sap/public/ap/ui/repository/SAP_UI/HTMLOBERON5/resources/~20171004110107.5183190~/sap/b/addon/themes/sap_belize/library.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-sap-ui-ready="true"></head>
<body class="sapUiSizeCompact sapBUiShellBackground" role="application" style=""><div id="sap-ui-static" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; overflow: hidden; float: left;" data-sap-ui-area="sap-ui-static"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiBLy" id="sap-b-ui-blocklayer-popup" style="left: 0px; top: 60px; right: 0px; bottom: 27px; display: none;"></div><span class="sapUiInvisibleText" id="__text1" aria-hidden="true" data-sap-ui="__text1">Aktualisieren mit F5</span></div>
    <div class="sapBUiContent" id="content" data-sap-ui-area="content"><div id="__shell0" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-ui="__shell0"><div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"><div class="sapBUiBelTitle" id="__title0" role="banner" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; width: 100%; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;" data-sap-ui="__title0" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true" data-sap-ui-popup="__title0"><div class="sapBUiNoPrint" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0;"><div tabindex="0" title="Work-Center-Navigation einblenden/ausblenden" class="sapBUiBelNavIcon sapBUiIcon-shellMenu sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__button0" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Work-Center-Navigation einblenden/ausblenden" data-sap-ui="__button0"></div><img class="sapBUiBelCompanyLogo" id="flexCompanyLogo" src="resources//sap//b//themes//sap_belize//img//branding_logo_belize.png"></div><div class="sapBUiNoPrint" style="flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; overflow: hidden; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><div class="sapBUiBelProductTitle" id="__text0" data-sap-ui="__text0">Mein Launchpad</div><span class="sapUiHiddenPlaceholder" id="sap-ui-invisible-__icon0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-sap-ui="sap-ui-invisible-__icon0"></span></div><div class="sapBUiBelPrintTitle">Mein Launchpad</div><div class="sapBUiNoPrint" style="display: flex; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; flex-grow: 0;"><div tabindex="0" title="Suchen" class="sapBUiBelTitleIconL sapBUiIcon-search" id="__button2" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Suchen" data-sap-ui="__button2"></div><div tabindex="0" title="Tony Ungrade" class="sapBUiBelTitleIconL sapBUiRoundButton" id="__button3" style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; align-items: center;" data-sap-ui="__button3"><div class="sapBUiRoundButtonIcon" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;"><div class="sapBUiRoundButtonIconImg" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; overflow: hidden;"><img style=" max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" src="resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/img/user_placeholder.jpg"></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Randleiste einblenden/ausblenden" class="sapBUiBelTitleIconL sapBUiIcon-help" id="__button1" role="button" style="cursor: pointer" aria-label="Randleiste einblenden/ausblenden" data-sap-ui="__button1"></div></div></div></div><div style="overflow: hidden; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1;"><div class="sapBUiNoPrint sapBUiToolboxBackground" style="display: flex; flex-shrink: 0;"><div class="sapBUiShMnu sapBUiShMnuCollapsed" id="__menu0" role="navigation" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow-x: hidden; width: 72px; " data-sap-ui="__menu0" data-sap-ui-fastnavgroup="true"><div class="scrollbox-y scrollbox-delayed" style="flex-grow: 1;"><div class="scrollbox-y-content sapBUiShMnuScrCont ui-sortable"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroupCont"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroup" id="__group0" data-sap-ui="__group0"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShMnuItem sapBUiShMnuItemHighlight sapBUiShMnuItemSelected sapBUiIconHintGray" id="__item5" data-sap-ui="__item5"><div class="sapBUiShMnuItemHint" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div><div title="Mein Launchpad" class="sapBUiShMnuItemIcon" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroupCont"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroup" id="__group1" data-sap-ui="__group1"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShMnuItem sapBUiIconHintGray" id="__item7" data-sap-ui="__item7"><div class="sapBUiShMnuItemHint" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div><div title="Startseite" class="sapBUiShMnuItemIcon" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuArrow sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" style="display: flex; flex-shrink: 0;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroupCont ui-sortable-handle"><div class="sapBUiShMnuGroup" id="__group2" data-sap-ui="__group2"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShMnuItem sapBUiIconHintGray" id="__item22" data-sap-ui="__item22"><div class="sapBUiShMnuItemHint" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div><div title="Projektteam" class="sapBUiShMnuItemIcon" style="flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; overflow: hidden;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuArrow sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" style="display: flex; flex-shrink: 0;" data-sap-b-icon-content=""></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShMnuFltr" style="flex-grow: 0;"><div class="sapMSF sapMSFDisabled" id="__field0" style="width:100%;" data-sap-ui="__field0"><form class="sapMSFF" id="__field0-F"><input disabled="disabled" class="sapMSFI" id="__field0-I" aria-disabled="true" type="search" placeholder="Suchen" autocomplete="off"></form></div></div><div style="display: none; height: 30px; flex-grow: 0;"><div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiToolboxSeparator"></div><div class="__sapBUiShHdr" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><div class="sapBUiShellMainCont" style="width: 100%; height: 253px; display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-grow: 1; align-items: stretch;"><div class="__sapUiBCATB" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 0; flex-shrink: 0; position: relative;"></div><div class="__sapUiBCACA" style="width: 1400.92px; height: 253px; display: flex; position: relative; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; align-items: stretch;"><div id="__presenter0" style="display: flex;  width: 100%; height: 100%;" data-sap-ui="__presenter0"><div class="sapBUiTransparentPaper" id="__component0" data-sap-ui="__component0"><table class="sapBUiContentTable"><tbody><tr class="sapBUiWcViewComponent"></tr><tr height="100%"><td style="vertical-align: top"><div class="sapBUiViewContainer" id="__container1" data-sap-ui="__container1"><div class="sapBUiComponent" style="padding-right: 0px;"><div class="sapFlexLPContainer" id="__view0" data-sap-ui="__view0"><div class="sapBUiLPTabBar sapBUiTSPne sapMITB sapMITBBackgroundDesignSolid" id="__bar0" data-sap-ui="__bar0"><div class="sapContrastPlus sapMITBNotScrollable sapMITH sapMITHBackgroundDesignSolid" id="__bar0--header" role="tablist" data-sap-ui="__bar0--header"><span class="sapMITBArrowScroll sapMITBArrowScrollLeftInLine sapMITBArrowScrollLeftTextOnly sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__bar0--header-arrowScrollLeft" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons'" data-sap-ui="__bar0--header-arrowScrollLeft" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span><div class="sapMITBScrollContainer" id="__bar0--header-scrollContainer" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden;"><div tabindex="0" class="sapMITBHead sapMITBInLine sapMITBTextOnly" id="__bar0--header-head"><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMITBFilter sapMITBFilterDefault sapMITBItem sapMITBItemNoCount sapMITBVertical sapMITBSelected" id="__filter0" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="__bar0-content" aria-labelledby="__filter0-text" data-sap-ui="__filter0"><div class="sapMITBText" id="__filter0-text" dir="ltr">Arbeit: Eingang</div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMITBFilter sapMITBFilterDefault sapMITBItem sapMITBItemNoCount sapMITBVertical" id="__filter1" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="__bar0-content" aria-labelledby="__filter1-text" data-sap-ui="__filter1"><div class="sapMITBText" id="__filter1-text" dir="ltr">Service und Support</div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" class="sapMITBFilter sapMITBFilterDefault sapMITBItem sapMITBItemNoCount sapMITBVertical" id="__filter2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="__bar0-content" aria-labelledby="__filter2-text" data-sap-ui="__filter2"><div class="sapMITBText" id="__filter2-text" dir="ltr">Favoriten</div><div class="sapMITBContentArrow"></div></div></div></div><span class="sapMITBArrowScroll sapMITBArrowScrollRightInLine sapMITBArrowScrollRightTextOnly sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__bar0--header-arrowScrollRight" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons'" data-sap-ui="__bar0--header-arrowScrollRight" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div><div class="sapMITBContentClosed" id="__bar0-containerContent"><div class="sapMITBContent" id="__bar0-content" role="tabpanel" style="display: none"></div></div></div><div class="sapMScrollCont sapMScrollContV" id="__container2" style="width: 100%; height: 186px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;" data-sap-ui="__container2"><div class="sapMScrollContScroll" id="__container2-scroll"><div class="sapBFlexCntArea" id="__area1" style="height: 590px;" data-sap-ui="__area1"><div class="sapBFlexQLGroup" id="__group3" data-sap-ui="__group3"><span class="sapFlexLPGroupHeader sapMText sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" id="__text4" style="text-align:left" data-sap-ui="__text4">Arbeit: Eingang</span><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Posten" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile0" data-sap-ui="__tile0"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Posten</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Posten" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon21" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon21" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Alarmmeldungen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile1" data-sap-ui="__tile1"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Alarmmeldungen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Alarmmeldungen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon23" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon23" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Aufgaben" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile2" data-sap-ui="__tile2"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Aufgaben</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Aufgaben" class="sapUiIcon" id="__icon25" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon25" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Benachrichtigungen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile3" data-sap-ui="__tile3"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Benachrichtigungen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Benachrichtigungen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon27" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon27" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Offene Rückfragen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile4" data-sap-ui="__tile4"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Offene Rückfragen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileCount sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">0</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Offene Rückfragen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon29" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon29" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBFlexQLGroup" id="__group4" data-sap-ui="__group4"><span class="sapFlexLPGroupHeader sapMText sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" id="__text5" style="text-align:left" data-sap-ui="__text5">Service und Support</span><div tabindex="0" title="Erste Schritte" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile5" style='width: 260px; background-image: url("resources/sap/b/themes/sap_belize/img/getting_started_tile2.png");' data-sap-ui="__tile5"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Erste Schritte</div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Idee einreichen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile6" data-sap-ui="__tile6"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Idee einreichen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Idee einreichen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon33" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon33" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="Community befragen" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile7" data-sap-ui="__tile7"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Community befragen</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="Community befragen" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon35" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon35" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div><div tabindex="0" title="One-Stop-Infocenter" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile8" data-sap-ui="__tile8"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">One-Stop-Infocenter</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span title="One-Stop-Infocenter" class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon37" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" data-sap-ui="__icon37" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBFlexQLGroup" id="__group5" data-sap-ui="__group5"><span class="sapFlexLPGroupHeader sapMText sapMTextBreakWord sapMTextMaxWidth sapUiSelectable" id="__text6" style="text-align:left" data-sap-ui="__text6">Favoriten</span><div tabindex="0" title="Startseite - Weitergegebene Aufgaben" class="sapBFlexTile sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl" id="__tile9" data-sap-ui="__tile9"><div class="sapBFlexTileInner"><div class="sapBFlexTileDescr sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl">Startseite - Weitergegebene Aufgaben</div><div class="sapBFlexTileIcon sapBUiMirrorElementInRtl"><span class="sapUiIcon sapUiIconMirrorInRTL" id="__icon39" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" style="font-family:'SAP-icons';color:#5683a9;font-size:2rem" aria-label="favorite" data-sap-ui="__icon39" data-sap-ui-icon-content=""></span></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div></div></div><div id="__presenter1" style="display: flex;  width: 100%;" data-sap-ui="__presenter1"><div class="sapBUiMessageAreaOverview" id="__area0" data-sap-ui="__area0"></div></div><span class="sapUiHiddenPlaceholder" id="sap-ui-invisible-__info0" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" data-sap-ui="sap-ui-invisible-__info0"></span></div><div style="display: flex; flex-grow:0; flex-shrink: 0;"></div></div><div class="sapBUiNoPrint sapBUiShTabSw" id="__switch0" data-sap-ui="__switch0" data-sap-ui-popup="__switch0"><div tabindex="0" class="sapBUiShTabSwHomeItem" id="__item0" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1;" data-sap-ui="__item0"><div class="sapBUiShTabSwItemInner" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1; overflow: hidden; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;"><div title="Mein Launchpad" class="sapBUiShTabSwItemTitleContainer" style="display: flex; flex-grow: 1; align-items: center; overflow: hidden;"><div class="sapBUiShTabSwItemText" style="display: flex; align-items: center; overflow: hidden;"><div style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Mein Launchpad</div></div></div></div></div><div class="sapBUiShTabSwPad"></div></div></div></div>
```